# File.ReadAllLines Ошибка

Tags: c#, visual-studio, файлы

Здраствуйте у меня ошибка

```
string text = File.ReadAllLines(Path.GetFullPath(openFileDialog.FileName));
```

[image: Err]

[image: err 2]

Мой код: https://pastebin.com/58MwqrYb
28 строка

Comment: ReadAllLines - прочитать все строки, логично предположить, что этот метод прочитает строки и вернёт массив, состоящий из них, верно? Так почему вы присваиваете массив к простому string?  Может вам не надо читать построчно, а надо лишь взять текст файла? Тогда для этого есть специальный метод и я думаю вы без труда его найдете следуя подсказкам студии.

Comment: уже понял readtext

Comment: но почемуто оно луа файл не видит

Comment: хотя я указал..

Comment: аа все понял работает